# Combine 2 byte arrays in 2 different Objects to a .Zip file in java

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 Objects which has byte arrays in each where each object represent .ABC file and .XYZ file formats respectively. Both these 2 objects/file formats needs to be part of a .Zip file which means **.ABC(JobExportDto)+.XYZ(JobExportDto) = .Zip(JobExportDto)** file

**.ABC file Format**

```
    @Data
    public class JobExportDto implements Serializable, IValidable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4230073680958541795L;
    
        private final byte[] exportFileBytes;
    
        @Override
        public boolean valid() {
            return this.exportFileBytes != null && this.exportFileBytes.length > 0;
        }
    }
```

**+**

**.XYZ file Format****

```
@Data
public class JobExportDto implements Serializable, IValidable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4230073680958541795L;

    private final byte[] exportFileBytes;

    @Override
    public boolean valid() {
        return this.exportFileBytes != null && this.exportFileBytes.length > 0;
    }
}
```

**=**

**.Zip File Format**

```
@Data
public class JobExportDto implements Serializable, IValidable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4230073680958541795L;

    private final byte[] exportFileBytes;

    @Override
    public boolean valid() {
        return this.exportFileBytes != null && this.exportFileBytes.length > 0;
    }
}
```

How to achieve the above?

Comment: No although the logic in the link is fine the final output would look something like byte[] result =byte[]+byte[] and then the resultant byte[] will be given a fileName. Most importantly we cannot append 2 byte[] to 1